# implementing associations into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, associations

suppose a PHP object is associated with another (one-to-one,many-to-many,etc), what is the best way to represent those associations in a database

I know that there are ORMs that do so, but how do these ORMs work when implementing these associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through multiple tables and surrogate keys.  Read this: [An Introduction to Database Normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)